# Ebay Daily Deals API

Tags: json, angularjs, ebay-api

I am trying to implement ebay's daily deals api.

[http://deals.ebay.com/feeds/json]

into my angular web application. The only problem is when I go to this url the json comes back is this:

```
   ({ebaydailydeals:{"items": [
 {
  "endtime": "1433170740000",
  "convertedcurrentprice": "329.99",
  "smallpictureurl": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/1kMAAOSwBLlVZc9d/$_1.JPG",
  "location": "Elizabeth, NJ",
  "pricedisplay": "MSRP",
  "itemid": "331566158178",
  "savingsrate": "40%",
  "title": "Acer Aspire E5 15.6\" Notebook - I5-4210U, 4GB Ram, 500GB HDD, Windows 8.1",
  "msrp": "549.99",
  "autopay": true,
  "description": "N/A",
  "primarycategoryid": "177",
  "quantity": 722,
  "picture175url": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/1kMAAOSwBLlVZc9d/$_1.JPG",
  "dealurl": "http://deals.ebay.com/5002063567",
  "pictureurl": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/1kMAAOSwBLlVZc9d/$_1.JPG",
  "primarycategoryname": "Computers/Tablets & Networking:Laptops & Netbooks:PC Laptops & Netbooks",
  "quantitysold": 88
},
```

If I copy the json into a formatter its saying the json is not valid. Before I spend any more time bulldogging this thing I am looking for some validation that this is doable or not.

Comment: You need to use jsonp, isn't there a callback fn name in front of it?

Comment: Do you know how JSON is formatted? This block isn't formatted correctly...it looks like a snippet of a bigger piece

Comment: I am well aware of how JSON is formatted this link is a snippet from http://deals.ebay.com/feeds/json

Comment: @PSL I saw http://www.helios825.org/eDD.php that the jsonp is no longer working

Comment: @JohnAlexander ohho.. never seen one like that... But this one seems like half jsonp it is a callback but no function name in the front.. dont know how to use it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to make a request to the following URL:

http://api.epn.ebay.com/deals/v1/country/us/feed/json?feedType=json

You can customize this as you please, here's some helpful documentation:

http://www.helios825.org/eDD.php

Comment: I saw that and the the link seems very odd but I will give that a try thanks